How to get the default parameters of a postGres connection?
I am experiencing an issue where my postGres client connection object goes 'stale' if I have not run a query on it for a while (say 1 hour). I believe it probably involves the idle timeout or stay-live process. Attempting to use the connection object causes the code to block for around 5 minutes before throwing an exception with this text:

SQL Error: server closed the connection unexpectedly This probably
means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the
request.

When I look here it suggests that the psycopg2.connect() function will recognize various parameters for the connect() method, some of which seem related to timeouts.
For example keepalives_idle, the doc says that "Controls the number of seconds of inactivity after which TCP should send a keepalive message to the server. A value of zero uses the system default. This parameter is ignored for connections made via a Unix-domain socket, or if keepalives are disabled. It is only supported on systems where TCP_KEEPIDLE or an equivalent socket option is available, and on Windows; on other systems, it has no effect." (I am on Windows).
But how do I find out what system default is being used.
If I try:
conn.info.parameter_status('keepalives_idle')
The result is None.

conn.info.parameter_status() only covers the parameters listed here libpq parameter status. keepalives_idle is not one of them. You might try conn.info.options.

@AdrianKlaver From what I read, conn.info.options only shows those parameters that were explicitly set in the connection string.

Which I pretty sure is the only place you can set them as they are client settings. Read this TCP keepalive it should make things clearer.

@AdrianKlaver Thanks for that link. I added keepalives_idle=600 to my connection string, and that seems to have done the trick. Seems the server has been timing out client connections after 90 mins, but the client idle is two hours unless I override.
